# JS For loop not iterating properly within an Ajax success response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Goal**

- Get array back from Ajax call
- Iterate over options in a select field "#id_asset_field" starting at 1
- If option's value is not in the array, remove the option

**What is happening:**

Correct behavior:

- Get array returned from Ajax call : [6,2,7]
- asset_field.length is 12

Incorrect behavior:

- JS loop only hits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
- Instead of leaving only options 6, 2, and 7, the result is [2,4,6,7,9,11].

**Code**

```
$("#id_portfolio_field").on('change', function() {
    var url = "/transactions/get/assets/" + $(this).val() + '/';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            var remove_list = []
            for (i = 1; i < asset_field.length; i++) {
                var _num = parseInt(asset_field.options[i].value)
                if (!(result['assets'].includes(_num))) {
                    remove_list.push(i)
                }
            }
            for (element in remove_list) {
                option = $(asset_field.options[remove_list[element]])
                console.log(remove_list[element] + ' ' + option[0])
                option.remove()
            }
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('Bug');
        },
    });
})
```

**Questions:**

- Any ideas why the for loop isn't iterating properly?
- My guess is if that is solved, it would properly remove the right options

**Update**

I updated the code off the initial comments. The remove_list now contains the list of elements I want to remove. However when I loop over that list, it doesn't remove the right elements.

[image]

Comment: At a glance, it looks like you're removing items from the array while you're iterating through it. That's always a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Yes I am. Thanks for quick reply, will change locally..

Comment: Work backwards so you don't mess up the indexing as you remove

Comment: @charlietfl how would you go about that? I changed it to build a list of the elements to remove, however when I loop over that list, it doesn't remove all of those elements.

Comment: To loop right to left: `for (var i =  asset_field.length-1; i >=0; i--) {`

Comment: @charlietfl that solved it. Much appreciated. If you want to throw an answer up, I'll select it